# Trying to call public async Task<Boolean> from a public string submit method

Tags: c#, boolean, async-await, salesforce, task

I'm pretty new to this Async thing. I'm trying to write in to an API using a createasync method. However, for some reason I either get an aggregate exception, or the thread just hangs depending on what I've tried. Here is a code example because I have yet to be able to successfully write in to the Salesforce API. I have been able however, to pull back data using similar operations.

Submit Method where I want this all to take place in my controller:

```
    [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
    public string Submit([FromBody]SurveyFormModel survey)
    {

        // todo - Validate data and stop if bad data comes in.            
        var report = BuildReport(survey.Questions);

        try
        {
            var task = Task.Run(async () => { await SendReportToSalesforce(survey); });
            task.Wait();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.GetBaseException();
        }

        EmailExcel(survey);
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(report);
    }
```

This is the method I'm using to call my salesforceservice.cs

```
public async Task SendReportToSalesforce([FromBody] SurveyFormModel survey)
    {
        SalesforceService service = new SalesforceService();
        var auth = service.Authenticate();
        var sfSurvey = service.SalesForceMapper(survey, survey.AccountDetails);
        var result = await service.SendSurveytoSF(auth.Result, sfSurvey); //.Wait();
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
```

Also included is the salesforceservice class I use to authenticate as well as the method (SendSurveytoSF) that doesnt seem to be working.

```
    public async Task<ForceClient> Authenticate()
    {
        //get credential values
        var consumerkey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["consumerkey"];
        var consumersecret =    ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["consumersecret"];
        var username = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["username"];
        var password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["password"];

        //create auth client to retrieve token
        var auth = new AuthenticationClient();

        //get back URL and token
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
        try
        {
            await
                auth.UsernamePasswordAsync(consumerkey, consumersecret, username, password,
                    "https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }

        var instanceUrl = auth.InstanceUrl;
        var accessToken = auth.AccessToken;
        var apiVersion = auth.ApiVersion;

        return new ForceClient(instanceUrl, accessToken, apiVersion);
    }
        public async Task<Boolean> SendSurveytoSF(ForceClient sfclient, Models.Salesforce.Survey survey)
    {
        survey.Account__c = "0012200000Ah3zG";
        var response = await sfclient.CreateAsync("VBR_Assessment__c", survey);
        return response.Id != null;
    }
```

I believe I'm maybe just not calling these methods properly, but at this point I really have no clue as I've tried implementing it a ton of different ways. Thank you for any help in advanced!

**UPDATE**

This is the exception I'm getting:

A first chance exception of type 'Salesforce.Common.ForceException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Comment: First off, if you are going to use async, you should use async from top to bottom.  As a result, Submit should be async as well and returning a task.  Second, what is the actual issue that you are running into?  We don't know what "doesn't seem to be working" means.

Comment: I guess the major issue is that when I try to call the SendSurveyToSF, my break point at this line just seems to get skipped over once the debugger goes in to that method
    return response.Id != null;

Comment: Try changeing Submit to `public Task<string> Submit` and just do `await SendReportToSalesforce(survey);` and get rid of the `Task.Run` That is what David is talking about. You are likely running in to the deadlock everyone runs in to when you try to mix async/await and `.Wait()` calls.

Comment: Just noticed this in the output window: A first chance exception of type 'Salesforce.Common.ForceException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Comment: @SamNatalini You need to enable [break on thrown exceptions in the debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x85tt0dd.aspx) then once you have the exception you need to [copy the exception detail to the clipboard](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/saraford/2008/08/07/did-you-know-you-can-copy-the-exception-details-with-one-click-from-the-exception-assistant-276/) and then paste the details in to your question.